# pm2 start without log stream to prevent timeout in github actions

Tags: node.js, github, process, github-actions, pm2

I have GitHub action to deploy the app to the server. I'm deploying the app and running a few commands to restart the app using ssh. Then, I'm starting the process using pm2. The problem is, It streams the log to the console `stdout`, and the Github action hags up with a timeout error. What I want to do is spawn the application instance without streaming the log to the console. Here is the command I'm using to start the app.

```sh
NODE_ENV=production && pm2 start ecosystem.config.json
```

and, here is the ecosystem configuration file.

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "apitoid",
      "script": "src/index.js",
      "instances": 1,
      "autorestart": true,
      "watch": false,
      "time": true,
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way I can prevent logging stream to stdout or no stdout in GitHub action workflow?